# mysql SELECT a whole column or cycle through all IDs

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select a whole column.
So my question is how do i get a whole column ?

```
        $query  = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM employees ";
        $query .= "WHERE id=*";
        $query .= "ORDER BY id ASC ";
```

I tried id=* but no luck ...
My goal is to cycle through all IDs but some may be missing so i figured i put them in a numeric or associative array and use foreach. If there is a better way , please do share.

EDIT:

```
function get_all_ids()
    {
        global $connection;
        $query  = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM employees ";
        $query_result = mysql_query ( $query , $connection );
        confirm_query($query_result);
        $query_result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result);
        return $query_result_array;
    }
```

i use this to print the array

```
  $all_id = get_all_ids();
// preparing the table;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($table);
    print_r($all_id);
    echo "</pre>";
```

and this is the array

```
  Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [department_id] => 1
        [name] => jordan
        [EGN] => 9108121544
        [email] => testEmail
        [address] => testAddress
        [country] => testCounty
    )
```

Comment: no luck , that just gives me the 1st row.

Comment: Are you sure there is more than one row in the DB?

Comment: yeah , i will update my question in a sec.

Comment: @Jordashiro Not possible, unless you have only one row in your table or are also using `LIMIT 0 1`

Comment: @Jordashiro Then there's something else odd going on.  Can you post more of your code?  Such as the actual function used to get results and how you're printing results?  I would next suspect you're using some sort of "get one" function that will only return one result.

Comment: @michael: that or the OP isn't doing a proper fetch loop and has just a single bare fetch call.

Comment: @MarcB That information was just added. When this (and my comment) was posted, the only code here was the SQL statement...

Comment: @Michael: at the time I put in the comment, the code sample wasn't present either, hence my suggestion.

Comment: @MarcB Oh sorry, I totally misread your comment. I thought you were chiding me for missing an obvious bug in the code :)

Comment: ok give me a second to post more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's more than one row in your result set, you need to keep fetching until all results are retrieved:

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table`');
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) != FALSE)
{
// Do something with *one* result
}
mysql_free_result($q);
```

If you'd like to retrieve all ids in a single fetch, you could do:

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) AS `id_list` FROM `table`');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
mysql_free_result($q);

$list_of_ids = explode(',', $row['id_list']);
```

**WARNING:** `GROUP_CONCAT()` usually has a result limit of 1024 bytes; meaning your results *will* be truncated for large tables. You could either resort to the first solution, or increase [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) for the current connection.

Comment: so i get the rows 1 by 1 and put them in an assoc array basically. I will try it in a moment

Comment: ...or - depending on the result-set's size - you could use the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want ALL the records then you dont need a `WHERE` condition at all.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean the simple:

```
SELECT id
FROM employees
ORDER BY id ASC
```

If this gives you only one row, then either you have only one row or you are adding a `LIMIT 1` or your PHP code does not loop through all the results but just shows the first one of them. Please add the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a single column. Then do not use "*", give the name of the columns name separated by comma and quoted with "`" (tick) for safety.

```
$query  = "SELECT `id` "; //if you only want to get ids from the table
$query .= "FROM employees ";
$query .= "WHERE id=*";
$query .= "ORDER BY id ASC ";
```